# maven build service liferay uncompilable code

Tags: maven, service, build, liferay

im trying to build an example code with maven liferay:build-service from an service.xml

There is simple entity company.

After code generating i have uncompilable code. I have tried another versions of maven plugins, but it didnt help.

Thanx

My pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>intlib-env</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>intlib-env Portlet</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-css</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>D:\portal\liferay\deploy</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>D:\portal\liferay\tomcat7\webapps</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>D:\portal\liferay\tomcat7\lib\ext</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>D:\portal\liferay\tomcat7\webapps\ROOT</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>6.1.2</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>portal-service</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>Liferay-v6.x-Runtime-Stub</id>
    <properties>
        <liferay.version>6.1.2</liferay.version>
        <liferay.maven.plugin.version>6.1.30.1</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
        <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>D:\portal\liferay\deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
        <liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>D:\portal\liferay\tomcat7\webapps</liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>
        <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>D:\portal\liferay\tomcat7\lib\ext</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
        <liferay.app.server.portal.dir>D:\portal\liferay\tomcat7\webapps\ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
    </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

and here the service.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 6.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_6_0_0.dtd">
<service-builder package-path="cz.sysnet.intlib.eia"> 
<author>EB</author> 
<namespace>EIA</namespace> 
<entity name="Company" local-service="true" remote-service="false"> 
<column name="Id" type="long" primary="true" /> 
<column name="ICO" type="String" /> 
<column name="name" type="String" />
<column name="companyId" type="long" /> 
<column name="groupId" type="long" />
<order by="asc"> 
<order-column name="name" />
</order>
<finder name="G_N" return-type="Collection"> 
<finder-column name="groupId" />
<finder-column name="name" />
</finder>
<finder name="GroupId" return-type="Collection">
<finder-column name="groupId" />
</finder>
<finder name="CompanyId" return-type="Collection">
<finder-column name="companyId" />
</finder>
</entity>
</service-builder>
```

Here are few of the errors after successfully generation of the code.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method update(Company, boolean) in the type BasePersistence<Company> is not applicable for the arguments (Company)  CompanyLocalServiceBaseImpl.java    /intlib-env2/src/main/java/cz/sysnet/intlib/eia/service/base    line 80 Java Problem
The method update(Company, boolean) in the type BasePersistence<Company> is not applicable for the arguments (Company)  CompanyLocalServiceBaseImpl.java    /intlib-env2/src/main/java/cz/sysnet/intlib/eia/service/base    line 276    Java Problem
The method update(Company, boolean) in the type BasePersistence<Company> is not applicable for the arguments (Company)  CompanyUtil.java    /intlib-env2/src/main/java/cz/sysnet/intlib/eia/service/persistence line 89 Java Problem
The method update(Company, boolean) in the type BasePersistence<Company> is not applicable for the arguments (Company, ServiceContext)  CompanyUtil.java    /intlib-env2/src/main/java/cz/sysnet/intlib/eia/service/persistence line 97 Java Problem
The method setModelClass(Class<Company>) is undefined for the type CompanyPersistenceImpl   CompanyPersistenceImpl.java /intlib-env2/src/main/java/cz/sysnet/intlib/eia/service/persistence line 169    Java Problem
The method setExpandoBridgeAttributes(ExpandoBridge) of type CompanyModel must override or implement a supertype method CompanyModel.java   /intlib-env2/src/main/java/cz/sysnet/intlib/eia/model   line 146    Java Problem
The method setExpandoBridgeAttributes(BaseModel<?>) of type CompanyModel must override or implement a supertype method  CompanyModel.java   /intlib-env2/src/main/java/cz/sysnet/intlib/eia/model   line 143    Java Problem
The method countWithDynamicQuery(DynamicQuery) in the type BasePersistence<Company> is not applicable for the arguments (DynamicQuery, Projection)  CompanyLocalServiceBaseImpl.java    /intlib-env2/src/main/java/cz/sysnet/intlib/eia/service/base    line 210    Java Problem
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx for the response,

i had to move from the newest version apache maven 3.2.2 to the 3.1.1 and cleaned the maven files in the project.

Now its working again.

Answer (score 0):

`Company` is a type that Liferay also has. Most likely ServiceBuilder generates import for Liferay's Company class, clashing with your own. Unless you want to start over, you'd have some tasks to do to get rid of all of your company declarations from the generated content of service builder - hibernate files, spring configuration and others. Search for `cz.sysnet.intlib.eia.Company` in your project and remove those declarations (and the `Company*` classes in your project), rename your entity (e.g. to `Kompany`, choose any other value that you like) and rebuild the services.

ServiceBuilder has a few limitations like these, after all, it's a code generator and rarely used to introduce another entity with an already existing name. You might want to add this limitation to [LPS-27710](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-27710) and watch that issue. It probably doesn't have the highest priority unless there's a lot of activity on there